# How do you set up the environment for es?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, profile, gdm

I've been playing with [es](http://wryun.github.com/es-shell/) the last couple of days, and it (like rc) has the quirk/feature that it only runs its startup script (`.esrc`) on login. The usual way to run code in each interactive session is to put that code in the `%prompt` function.

Of course, there's no `%prompt` function if `es -l` has never been run.

So, the question: how do you set the login environment when you come in via gdm or similar, which only source .profile (or .xprofile, .xsession, etc.)? The best I've come up with is:

```
if [ -f "$HOME/.esrc" ]; then
    eval "`es -l <<-x
        sh <<<'export -p'
    x`"
fi
```

Which seems... horrifying. Any better approaches?

Comment: I gather that `es` is not your login shell.  What about setting `alias es='es -l'` in `.bashrc`?

Comment: `es` is my login shell. Sorry if I didn't make that clear. But login shells aren't run in X sessions before terminals are launched, at least as far as I know.

Comment: I use `bash`, not `es`.  But when I open a new terminal window, it runs `bash` as a login shell.

Comment: At least with most X terminals, this is an option that is disabled by default (as it should be, IMO). So yes, it is a workaround, but there's no reason this stuff should be run multiple times when it could be run once.

Comment: Hmm, not sure I agree with your edit, Gilles. Why do you think this only applies to es? (and not *csh or rc or ...?) And why remove gdm and lightdm, since they're the ones that control the environment?

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has a real answer, here's my horrible hack.  Some shells (*rxvt for example) have settings that allow to force a login shell.  So, in your `.Xdefaults`, you can add something akin to

```
urxvt256c-ml:loginShell: true
```

Which means that all `urxvt256c-ml` terminal you launch will have a login shell by default.

Does that help at all?

Comment: Well, being an annoying person (see comments above?), I'll say I already knew about this. It's a toss-up whether this or my slightly disturbing code is a better option; one lacks conceptual elegance (I'm claiming that I log in for every terminal, when I create 100s over a single real login?), the other lacks implementation elegance (but I really feel the environment _should_ be set up on login).

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean now. Personally, I consider a terminal to be a the unit of login not the X11 environment so it makes sense to me to be logged in three times if I have three terminals open.  I'll leave the answer here just in case it is useful for others -- let's see how many down votes is attracts. ^_~

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question all these years later, gnome-session now appears to do some magic which extracts environment variables from the login shell and tells dbus about them, and .profile is not run:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-session/-/blob/ef9f3039bdb48e008cd59e46aac442811bc40f09/gnome-session/gsm-util.c#L545

Unfortunately, it also refuses to export things it doesn't like, which (in 2023) includes long strings due to:

https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/glib/-/issues/2824